# Populating Android Spinner with data retrieved from an asp.net WebService

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services, spinner, populate

So I am actually trying to retrieve the data I have in my asp.net web service and pass it on to an android spinner. I am having a hard time making it since I only receive force close error or null values.

I used these sites for the codes I have, [site1](http://andygeeks.blogspot.in/2014/01/populate-spinners-using-string-array.html) and [site2](http://androiddev.orkitra.com/?p=3448)
So here is my WebService:

```
[WebMethod]
    public ArrayList GetCustomerList()
    {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        SqlConnection con = DB.GetConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Regions";
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            list.Add(reader["regName"].ToString());
        }
        con.Close();
        list.ToArray();
        return list;
    }
```

This is my android code which only gives me a null value:
Main Activity;

```
package com.example.lainnasad;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String[] regionList;
String regions;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new region().execute();
}

class region extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetCustomerList";
        final String METHOD_NAME = "GetCustomerList";
        final String URL = "http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:xxxx/WebPopulate.asmx";
        final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";

        SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);
        Bean C = new Bean();
        PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
        pi.setName("Bean");
        pi.setValue(C);
        pi.setType(C.getClass());
        Request.addProperty(pi);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
        envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "Bean", new Bean().getClass());
        HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        aht.debug = true;

        try {
            System.out.println("Request:"+Request);
            aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
            System.out.println("MainActivity.onCreate()"+response);
            envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "Bean",new Bean().getClass());
            aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            Bean[] countrylist = new Bean[response.getPropertyCount()];

            for (int j = 0; j < countrylist.length; j++) {
            SoapObject pii = (SoapObject) response.getProperty(j);
            Bean beanobject = new Bean();
            beanobject.Region = pii.getProperty(0).toString();
            countrylist[j] = beanobject;
            System.out.println("person: " + beanobject.Region);
            }

            int i = 0;
            regionList = new String[countrylist.length];
            for (i = 0; i < countrylist.length; i++) {
            regionList[i] = Arrays.asList(countrylist[i].Region).toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
            System.out.println("stringarray: " + regionList);
            }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        spinner1meth();
    }


}

public void spinner1meth(){

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,regionList);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

And Here is the Bean class:

```
package com.example.lainnasad;

import java.util.Hashtable;

import org.ksoap2.serialization.KvmSerializable;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;

public class Bean implements KvmSerializable {

public String Region;

public Bean(){}

public Bean(String Region,String State) {
this.Region= Region;
//this.State=State;
}

@Override
public Object getProperty(int arg0) {
switch(arg0)
{
case 0:
return Region;
}
return null;
}

@Override
public int getPropertyCount() {
return 1;
}
@Override

public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo info) {
switch(index)
{
case 0:
info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
info.name = "Country";
break;
default:
break;
}
}

@Override
public void setProperty(int index, Object value) {
switch(index)
{
case 0:
Region= value.toString();
break;
default:
break;
}
}

}
```

Can you please help me what's missing? Thank you in advance!

Here is what is placed on log-cat. I find it confusing. I'm sorry. Just starting android.

```
02-06 07:01:07.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1449): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-06 07:01:07.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1449): Process: com.example.lainnasad, PID: 1449
02-06 07:01:07.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1449): java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null
02-06 07:01:07.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:38)
02-06 07:01:07.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:155)
02-06 07:01:07.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:128)
02-06 07:01:07.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at   com.example.lainnasad.MainActivity.spinner1meth(MainActivity.java:104)
02-06 07:01:07.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at com.example.lainnasad.MainActivity$region.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:94)
02-06 07:01:07.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at com.example.lainnasad.MainActivity$region.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
02-06 07:01:07.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
02-06 07:01:07.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
02-06 07:01:07.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
02-06 07:01:07.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-06 07:01:07.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-06 07:01:07.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
02-06 07:01:07.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-06 07:01:07.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-06 07:01:07.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
02-06 07:01:07.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
02-06 07:01:07.862: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I've changed the other code i posted to this one. Still getting these errors.

Comment: Just post your error in logcat we need to know what went wrong.

Comment: @Yashwanth : I changed the first code I posted to this other one I've created but still giving some errors. I've posted the log cat too. On the first code I posted, no errors are displayed on the log cat which i find very confusing..

Comment: Make sure your Web service returns value. And your url is correct.what does this line System.out.println("MainActivity.onCreate()"+response); print

Comment: I actually just based that code from the sites i've placed above but as i've observed in the logcat, i guess that line outputs the array of string from the webservice.

Comment: there is somesort of this line in the logcat..
    02-06 11:52:48.375: I/System.out(1269): MainActivity.onCreate()anyType{anyType=NCR; anyType=CAR; anyType=REGION I; anyType=REGION II; anyType=REGION III; anyType=REGION IV-A; anyType=REGION IV-B; anyType=REGION V; anyType=REGION VI; anyType=REGION VII; anyType=REGION VIII; anyType=REGION IX; anyType=REGION X; anyType=REGION XI; anyType=REGION XII; anyType=REGION XIII; anyType=ARMM; }

Comment: which i think is the purpose of that line, to make sure that the retrieve value is displayed and found before it's going to be passed on to the spinner but its forced closing @Yashwanth

Comment: Lets continue the discussion in my blog.